# How to run GrailsPlugin.groovy during 'war'

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Grails Version: 2.3.11

Dear all,

I have a plugin where in the doWithSpring Closure I use some central resources to build up a properties file in the war that is then used during runtime. The central resources will only be available when building the war in a production environment so putting the files into the /src (for example) of the plugin is out of the question.

Currently my plugin will work in a run-app and testing environment, but the file is never created when 'war' is run.

I have tried setting the scopes variable to include war but this doesn't appear to be doing much (or at least, is not invoking the doWithSpring closure). Does anyone know how to do this or if it is possible?

All of the logic is within doWithSpring (which delegates to a class) but that is only using the classLoader and grailsApplication so if there is anywhere else I can do this that will also be great.

Thanks

Adam

Comment: Are you trying to exclude files from being included in your WAR? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: No. To summarise I want to know how to run the GrailsPlugin.config during the 'war' process as I need the doWithSpring closure to be executed when the war is built. If that is not possible, I want to know if there is any other way of executing plugin code during the war process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the best approach is to hook into the events with your plugin. I highly recommend you read the documentation on [events](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#events). It's as simple as creating the correct file within your plugin and placing your code within the associated closure.

For example:

**scripts/_Events.groovy**

```
eventCreateWarStart = { warName, stagingDir ->
 // place your code here.
}
```